# Pop up window in vpython

Tags: python, vpython

is there anyway to have a small window pop up in vpython? Im trying to have a save button that when you press it would open a window to type in the file name was just wondering if this is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Vpython allows you to create 2D buttons and menus within the canvas. You could activate a button constructor via a key binding. That would allow you to access a file dialog then destroy itself after use. This should achieve your objective.

Answer (score 0):

In the widget documentation at

https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/controls.html

see the input() function. Also see read_local_file() described at

https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/files.html